# How can I reinitialize the Batchnorm Layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, batch-normalization

I have a [CNN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network) with batchnorm layers. I am trying to train the CNN for a few epochs, and then I want to reset the batchnorm weights (`moving_mean` and `moving_variance`) while preserving the learned CNN weights.

Is there a way of doing this?

I thought of using `build_from_config`  ([reference)](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer#build_from_config), but in Keras, batchnorm doesn't store its input shape in the configuration dictionary (you can see the code [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/b3ffea6602dbbb481e82312baa24fe657de83e11/keras/layers/normalization/batch_normalization.py#L809)).

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way to do this, but it's probably a bit unorthodox since it uses Keras private variables from [base_layer.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/0bfaafdbc747679d065452bdaff2bb7efaebafdd/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L371).

```
    for layer in model.layers:  #Find the Batch Norm Layers in the Model
         if layer.__class__.__name__ == 'BatchNormalization':
              layer.build(layer._build_input_shape)
```

I'll leave the question open in case a better (more "Pythonic") solution exists.